# Forward a GraphQL Subscription (Websocket) request to another service

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, graphql

I have 3 services (let's call them ServiceA, ServiceB, and ServiceC).

ServiceC has a GraphQL endpoint for subscriptions:

```
type Subscription {
   people: [People]
}
```

ServiceA needs to set up a Websocket and call ServiceC for the `people` subscription request. However, ServiceA will not be able to call ServiceC directly, it needs to call ServiceB. ServiceB needs to accept the request from ServiceA, and just forward it to ServiceC. Is that possible? I thought of setting up a GraphQL subscription in ServiceB and have ServiceA connect to that, then have ServiceB create a Websocket and call ServiceC's subscription request. But that seems like excessive work when it should be able to just forward the request from ServiceA to ServiceC.

For ServiceA and ServiceC, I am unable to make changes to their code. ServiceA will just point to ServiceB. I can make my changes in ServiceB.

ServiceB uses Java 21, Spring Boot 3.2.2, and uses spring-boot-starter-graphql.

Is it possible to just forward the request?